# Several dropdowns in one component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have several dropdowns menu in one component.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"> 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button @click="showInfo(index)"></button>
    <div v-show="isOpen">{{ item.content }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**vue:**

```
showInfo(index) {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
},
```

I feel like i need to use **index**, but still doesn't work for me. What i miss?

Comment: `this.isOpen` will be the same for all of them. `this` refers to your component, not your dropdown.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I just need to make another one component for dropdown? (child)

Comment: You can make the dropdown its own component, yes. Or make `isOpen` also an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can save index in isOpen and then check it in template:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{content: 1}, {content: 2}, {content: 3}],
      isOpen: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showInfo(index) {
      this.isOpen = this.isOpen === index ? null : index;
    },
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"> 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button @click="showInfo(index)">show</button>
    <div v-show="isOpen === index">{{ item.content }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a very simple manner by just playing around with the `itemIndex` variable.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
        name: 'Dropdown Menu 1',
      options: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
    }, {
        name: 'Dropdown Menu 2',
      options: ['Option 4', 'Option 5', 'Option 6']
    }],
    itemIndex: null
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F2C777;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7C785B;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #EC8C65;
}   
li {
  display: inline-block;
} 

.droplinks {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F2D299;
  min-width: 140px;
  display: block;
}

.droplinks a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="dropbutton" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <a @click="itemIndex = itemIndex ? null : index">{{ item.name }}</a>
        <div class="droplinks" v-if="itemIndex === index">
          <a href="" v-for="(option, i) in item.options" :key="i">{{ option }}</a>
        </div>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```